# How can I get seven segments clock programatically in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am developing a android application to show the digital clock.But I need to show the clock in seven segments form. I am not getting seven segments clock. Please can anybody help me by providing the code to get the seven segments clock view.

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in component or asking for someone to code a 7seg display for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no LED-style seven-segments widget or font in Android. If you can find a TrueType font that meets your needs, add it to your app and apply it to a `TextView` using a `Typeface` object.